# What information does variable "scope type" provide that is not already described by variable "linkage type"?

Tags: c, variables, scope, variable-declaration, linkage

In the book "*C Programming: A Modern Approach*", Chapter 18 takes on some of the more technical features of declarations. On page 459, the author states that a variable in a C program has three properties:

1. Storage Duration - (*automatic* vs *static*)
2. Scope - (*block* vs *file*)
3. Linkage - (*external* vs *internal* vs *none*)

I've poked around on several different websites and several differ S.O. posts, but I am still having some difficulties understanding the differences between ***scope*** and ***linkages***.

One of the major conceptual difficulties I have is determining the **unique information** that is provided by specifying the scope of a variable ***that is not already given by the linkage type***. There seem to be some nuances that I am completely missing.

Consider the following examples of declarations for variables:

---

Case 1:

```
void foo(void)
{
  static int j;  /* block scope + no linkage */
}
```

---

Case 2:

```
int i; /* file scope + external linkage */

int main(void)
{
  .
  .
  .
}
```

---

Case 3:

```
static int i; /* file scope + internal linkage */

int main(void)
{
  .
  .
  .
}
```

---

If you look at the 3 cases, you see that **block scope pairs with no linkage** and **file scope pairs with either internal or external linkage**.

Therefore, I see no information that is **added** by specifying the scope. That is to say:

1. If I know a variable has the feature *no linkage*, then I know that the scope type must be *block*
2. If I know a variable has the feature *internal linkage* or *external linkage*, then I know that the scope type must be *file*.

I am unfamiliar with code that utilizes  *block scope* with *internal linkage*. I am unfamiliar with code that utilizes *block scope* with *external linkage*. Finally, I am unfamiliar with code that uses *file scope* with *no linkage*.

So it seems like the **type of linkage provides all the relevant information needed**...so what exactly is the point of scope?

Thanks!

Edit:

Said differently, these terms are **not independent** (there are certain combinations that simply don't exist, at least that's how it seems).

Here's a picture that I think captures the idea correctly:

[image: Linkage Hierarchy]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580038/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-and-linkage

Comment: @user10191234 that is actually one of the posts I went through prior to asking this question. I did not acquire the answer I was hoping for. Referring specifically to MY question, could you provide an example of code that has "file scope with no linkage" or "block scope with internal/external linkage"? If not, then my question remains.

Comment: I see only one explicit question. _what is the point of scope_? In part, _scope_ means range of visibility, and duration of life, and by being cognizant of the concept it allows compartmentalization which in turn can provide limited or project global visibility and memory conservation.  (I.e limited life of automatics etc.). Static linkage still provides limited visibility while also extending life to the end of execution providing it's own set of benefits.

Comment: @ryyker The point of my question (the most important "explicit" one being the question embedded within the title) is that scope, in my opinion, seems like a property of linkage type rather than a property of a variable...so the way that this concept is commonly taught seems slightly wrong to me. And sure...linkage type is a property of a variable, and therefore you could view scope as a property type of that variable...but it is a more "distal" property of the variable.

Comment: Whether you think of it as external (simpler than saying distal) to the variable or not, a variables scope is an important property. It is with that variable for its entire life.

Comment: @ryyker I think you misunderstood what I meant by "distal". I attached a photo in my post that clears up the confusion.My point is that the way the author teaches these 3 concepts (storage duration, scope, and linkage) is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

While there is a relationship between scope and linkage, they represent two separate concepts.

Also, the C standard defines *four* different scopes for identifiers:

- File
- Block
- Function
- Function Prototype

This is specified in section 6.2.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> For each different entity that an identifier designates, the
> identifier is *visible* (i.e., can be used) only within a region of
> program text called its *scope*.  Different entities designate dby the
> same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different name
> spaces.  There are  four  kinds  of  scopes:  **function,  file,  block,
> and  function  prototype**.   (A *function prototype* is a declaration
> of a function that declares the types of its parameters.)

The only identifiers that have *function scope* are labels.  A label can be references anyplace within the function were it is declared.

Identifiers with *function prototype* are function parameters that appear in a declaration of a function.  For example:

```
void foo(int x);   //  x has function prototype scope
```

For identifiers with function scope or function prototype scope, they do not represent an object.  Then in those cases the identifier has no linkage.  Section 6.2.2p6 states:

> The following identifiers have no linkage: **an identifier declared to
> be anything other than an  object  or  a  function**;  an  identifier
> declared  to  be  a  function  parameter;  a  block  scope identifier
> for an object declared without the storage-class specifier `extern`

So to answer your question, the linkage of an identifier doesn't imply its scope.  An identifier with no linkage could have block scope, function scope, or function prototype scope.